# Trying to get JSON from MVC Controller and getting error net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get JSON from my controller to use in jQuery. I have the following code. When I visit the URL in my browser it returns the json so I know that the controller is working... But I get the following

> GET http://localhost:52802/Checkout/GetContactById?id=1 net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

#### client-side jQuery

```
var theUrl = window.location.origin + '/Checkout/GetContactById?id=' + contactId;

$.ajax({
    url: theUrl,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

#### Server-side Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetContactById(int id)
{
  Contact contact = this.checkoutDataAccess.GetContactById(id);
  return Json(contact);
}
```

The only alert I get is "Error"

#### Update

After more research it looks like everything is loading... but I am getting an error

> Failed to load response data

in the console.

I stepped through the code and everything works on the controller side. I am not sure if it is not formatting the JSON correct, or if I am not receiving it correctly. Either way I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response - it will give your more details on the error.

Comment: have you tested GetContactById method work?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is giving a 500 error I put more details in the post with the error I am getting

Comment: @DanielVorph yes, however I did not test it when it was being called from the json, just from visiting the URL directly. I was able to recreate the error when I stepped through after calling it through JSON. I put the details and exception error in the post above as an update

Comment: Your method is a GET, so it needs to be `return Json(contact, JsonResuestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was under the impression when trying to add that already that JsonRequestBehavior has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core

Comment: You have not tagged the question asp.net-core-mvc :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that error was actually because I had to AJAX calls being called when I added a sugestion from here to test. So that error is not gone since I only have one call, but I am not getting the error "Unable to load response data" in the developer tools network tab.

Comment: what about test it in fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are getting the text Error since you put alert("Error");
Try alert(error); instead
Or try debugging using firebug

Comment: That alert is just a quick way of seeing where the ajax was hitting since the chrome tools do not allow me to step through it. So it is just showing me that it is in the error section. I need to get the Success alert to work to get the json.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding datatype JSON to the ajax call.

And maybe try adding the parameter in the body.

like so:

```
var theUrl = window.location.origin + '/Checkout/GetContactById';

$.ajax({
   url: theUrl,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   data: { id: contactId },
   success: function (result) {
      alert("Success");
   },
   error: function (error) {
      alert("Error");
   }
});
```

And i would suggest using Url.Action helper.

like:

```
 $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("GetContactById", "Checkout")',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data: { id: contactId },
       success: function (result) {
         alert("Success");
       },
       error: function (error) {
          alert("Error");
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and after looking for several possible solutions, I've tried to consume my api form Postman and discovered that I was returning a bad formed JSON.
In my case was because one of properties of my ViewModel was int[] type. After remove this property I could retrieve data normally.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I had an issue with recursive loading and Entity framework. Entity framework was loading entities recursively, and JSON serializer produced too large json response.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => 
     options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30468905)