# Serialized C# class in controller receiving null values from axios post request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, axios

I am setting up a new controller using an existing C# class that serializes its properties. Class Definition as follows:

```
[Serializable]
    public class SomeLocationInfo
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Medium { get; set; }
        public List<ParameterPairs> ParameterPairsInfo { get; set; }

        SomeLocationInfo()
        {
            ParameterPairsInfo = new List<ParameterPairs>();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ParameterPairs
    {
        public string Parameter { get; set; }
        public string Units { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a new post endpoint that is as follows:

```
  [RoutePrefix("api/EnvdbMaps")]
  public class MapsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("RetrieveSelectedParametersForLocation")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RetrieveSelectedParametersForLocation(SomeLocationInfo locationData)

        {
            if (location.Medium == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                // DO THINGS HERE 
                return Json("things were done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // DO THINGS HERE
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
  }
```

In my JS file I have a call to this endpoint.

```
 try {
    const locationData = {
                SampleLocation: locationName,
                Medium: mediumName,
                ParameterPairs: [{
                            Parameter: parameterName,
                            Units: unitAmount
                           }]
                  };
                               
    const { data: response} = await axios.post(`/api/EnvdbMaps/RetrieveSelectedParametersForLocation/`, locationData);
                                
      } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
     };
```

Here's the issue:

The call in the browser's network tab had the correct data in the api call, and datatypes matched what was expected on the server. My debugging  breakpoint in C# server endpoint was hit each time as well. However the parameter value passed into the api endpoint was always a default object (i.e. Medium = null, etc.).

After a lot of experimentation, we discovered that removing `[Serializable]` attribute from the C# class definition fixed the error. We do have some old WebAPI code this class is used in, and removing the attribute would likely cause other issues.

Can anyone explain why this tag causes my values to be null on the server? Is there a way to reuse this class in both situations and not require a workaround class that doesn't have the `[Serializable]` tag?

Comment: Very old question but maybe it will help: [make-json-net-and-serializable-attribute-work-together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914080/make-json-net-and-serializable-attribute-work-together)

Answer (score 1):

your c# SomeLocationInfo class and javascript object have different property names, you will never get any data, till you fix it. I don't know the verison Net  you are using,but maybe you will need to add [FromBody] attribute to action input parameters.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I updates the names in my question. Typo. I am able to get the values after I remove the serializable tag. We did try using the FromBody as well and made no difference

Comment: @JoshuaGulledge  It is called  a typo if one letter is not correct, but when the most words are different it is called a bug. What version net are you using?

Comment: that would be .net framework 4.8