# Using Serializable attribute on Model in WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, serializable

I have the following scenario: I am using WebAPI and returning JSON results to the consumer based on a model. I now have the additional requirement to serialize the models to base64 to be able to persist them in cache and/or use them for auditing purposes. Problem is that when I add the `[Serializable]` attribute to the model so for converting the the model to Base64, the JSON output changes as follows:

The Model:

```
[Serializable]
public class ResortModel
{
    public int ResortKey { get; set; }

    public string ResortName { get; set; }
}
```

Without the `[Serializable]` attribute the JSON output is:

```
{
    "ResortKey": 1,
    "ResortName": "Resort A"
}
```

With the `[Serializable]` attribute the JSON output is:

```
{
    "<ResortKey>k__BackingField": 1,
    "<ResortName>k__BackingField": "Resort A"
}
```

How would I be able to use the `[Serializable]` attribute without changing the output of the JSON?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By default, Json.NET ignores the `Serializable` attribute. However, according to a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12844557/2700399) by [Maggie Ying](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672536/maggie-ying) (quoted below because comments are not meant to last), WebAPI overrides that behavior, which causes your output.

> Json.NET serializer by default set the IgnoreSerializableAttribute to true. In WebAPI, we set that to false. The reason why you hit this issue is because Json.NET ignores properties: "Json.NET now detects types that have the SerializableAttribute and serializes all the fields on that type, both public and private, and ignores the properties" (quoted from [james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/11/…](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/11/json-net-4-5-release-2-serializable-support-and-bug-fixes))

A simple example that demonstrates the same behavior without WebAPI can look like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
namespace Scratch
{
    [Serializable]
    class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var foo = new Foo() { Bar = "Blah" };
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
                    {
                        IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

There are several ways around this behavior. One is to decorate your model with a plain `JsonObject` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Another way is to override the default settings in your `Application_Start()`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11421486/2700399), the default settings should do it:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
```

If that doesn't work, you could be explicit about it:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Bart, great answer! I went for using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();` so as not to have to decorate every single model with `[JsonObject]`