# Getting a serialized object from a webservice

Tags: c#, ajax, serializable

I am coding a `C# Web API 2` webservice where I am getting a simple object with some `AJAX` code. The object is being returned correctly, however, if the exact same object has a `[Serializable]` attribute, then the `AJAX` code is not working correctly.

Here is the simple object:

```
public class Simple
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `AJAX` code:

```
function sendRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: serviceUrl2,
            beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(userName, password)); 
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        alert('data:' + data.data);
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#value1').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
    });
}
```

The above code works correctly, and an alert is shown with the data.

If the same object is coded as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class Simple
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

The above code does not work correctly, and an alert is shown with "data:undefined"

Here is the `Web API` function:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[Route("Getsimple")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Simple))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSimple()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {

    }
    var simple = new Simple();
    simple.number = 1;
    simple.data = "test data";
    return Ok(simple);
}
```

Do I need to add a specific parameter to the `AJAX` code or do I need to serialize the `Simple` object before the object is returned? If not, how can I get the code working?

Comment: can you modify your `alert('data:' + data.data);` line with `alert('data:' + JSON.stringify(data));` and post here what you see?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Serializable attribute on Model in WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962044/using-serializable-attribute-on-model-in-webapi)