# Serializable class invokes json with null properties

Tags: c#, json, serializable

I'm having problems with my serializable class

```
[Serializable]
public class MyNameIsClass
```

All the properties are getting the default value (null or 0) when invoking from external sources. I deleted the [Serializable] tag and worked, but I need the class to be serializable so I can run this line:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = StreamHelper.SerializeToStream(myNameIsClassObject);
```

Is there another way to go through this problem?

Thank you all

Comment: When invoking are you creating an instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Serializable attribute on Model in WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962044/using-serializable-attribute-on-model-in-webapi)

Comment: @MaxCheetham I'm using postman and sending the JSON as the body of the request. Basically I'm creating an instance when calling from the external source =) thank you!

Comment: @Xeno-D oops! thanks! I'll take a look at that!